# How to get purchaseToken from an in-app already purchased in android/server?

Tags: php, android, in-app-purchase, android-billing

I have an application where purchase flow is:

1. User uses MYAPP to purchase a item (inapp purchase)
2. MYAPP communicates with Google servers to initiate a purchase
3. Google Server gives a purchaseToken to MYAPP
4. MYAPP sends the purchaseToken to MYSERVER
5. MYSERVER uses `PHP` and `Purchase Status API` to validate the purchase and give "itemX" to user.

I have a problem, at some point after step 3, MYAPP lost communication and step 4 was unsuccessful. So user was billed but don't have "itemX" in your "items".

I look on Google Developer Console, but it only shows an "Order Id", but not purchaseToken.

Is there a way to obtain the lost purchaseToken from MYAPP/MYSERVER/GOOGLECONSOLE so i can restore this purchase to this user?

Comment: No, i didn't found solution for this :(

Comment: You can restore everything but the purchase tokens, via Google Developer Console. I suppose you could do that and then, when the user initializes `IabHelper`, you update your table with the purchase token.

Comment: My problem was the android app was marking items as consumed (using consumePurchase() function); so google were not sending purchase info anymore about this item.